# How to count the number of text lines inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

So do any of yall know how to check if my text which is inside a div tag passes over lines, if so i could add a pop up using bootstrap to show the rest of the text.

jsp:

```
  <div id="menu-description" class="description-wrapper" data-toggle="popover"
        data-placement="bottom" data-content="${product.description}">
      ${product.description}
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

So the above code contains the pop over code part, what i need to achieve is that if text (the description) inside exceeds 2 lines only i need to show pop up, not when there is one line cuz it doesnt make any sense if so.

FYI: i have included the ellipses by using the webkit to set the 2 dots '..' if it extends 2 lines, i just need to knw whether is there any similar way i could only show the pop up when it exceeds 2 lines..

Is there anyway i could achieve this?

Comment: How do you define that text exceeds a line?  Are you wanting to account for just new lines, or are you looking to account for soft/hard wrapping?

Comment: So basically i have included the ellipses by using the webkit to set the 2 dots '..' if it extends 2 lines, i just need to knw whether is there any similar way i could only show the pop up when it exceeds 2 lines.. @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the problem is as follows: you want to detect a moment when the text in the div takes more than two lines. In most cases we don't set fixed horizontal size on div containers to keep the whole page structure flexible. That's why the same block of text may take different line number depending on a current window width. To overcome this problem we may use Resize Observer API. If we know the line height and the height of the div container we can find out when the texts takes more than two lines.

Here is a code example that you may test in codepen.io.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <p id="text">Short text</p>
</div>
<button id="add-text">Add text</button>
<button id="clear-text">Clear text</button>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d4f4c7;
}
#text {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

JS:

```
const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
     const p = entry.target,
           height = entry.target.offsetHeight;
     let lineHeight = window
                      .getComputedStyle(p)
                      .getPropertyValue('line-height')
                      .replace('px', '') / 1;
     if (height/lineHeight >= 2) {
       alert('Too many lines');
     }
  }
});
ro.observe(document.querySelector('#text'));
document
  .querySelector('#add-text')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
     const newText = 'The very long story about one request that could not be resolved';
     const text = document.querySelector('#text');
     text.innerHTML = newText;
  });
document
  .querySelector('#clear-text')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
     const newText = 'Short text';
     const text = document.querySelector('#text');
     text.innerHTML = newText;
  });
```